# Ramda - reduce parentheses nesting on composition

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have an array like this:

```js
const arr = [
  ['1 1 1', '', '2 2 2'], 
  ['', '3 3 3', '4 4 4']
]
```

and my goal is to convert it to this array:

```js
[
  [ [1,1,1], [2,2,2] ],
  [ [3,3,3], [4,4,4] ]
]
```

I am trying to do that in functional way using function composition. I am also using Ramda.

I have this code

```js
const filterEmpty = filter(o(not, isEmpty));

const getFinalArr = map(
  compose( map(map(parseInt)), map(split(' ')), filterEmpty )
)

console.log(getFinalArr(arr))
```

Is there way to write it with less `map` nesting? I tried something like this:

```js
const getFinalArr = map(
  compose( parseInt, map, map, split(' '), map, filterEmpty )
)
```

But of course it did not work.

Or if there is another way to easily deal with arrays nested like this, I would appreciate learning about that.

Comment: Could be `arr.map(a => [].concat(a.reduce((r,s) => s.length ? (r.push(s.split(" ").map(s => +s)),r):r,[])));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When things start to get long and confusing I prefer `R.pipe` on `R.compose`, and writing the function where each line represents one transformation:

```js
const { map, pipe, reject, isEmpty, split } = R

const fn = map(pipe(
  reject(isEmpty), // remove empty items
  map(split(' ')), // convert string to sub-arrays
  map(map(Number)), // convert sub-arrays to arrays of numbers  
))

const arr = [['1 1 1', '', '2 2 2'], ['', '3 3 3', '4 4 4']]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Although there is still nested `map(map(...))` it looks a lot nicer than mine version.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure javascript:

```js
const arr = [
  ['1 1 1', '', '2 2 2'], 
  ['', '3 3 3', '4 4 4']
]

function foo(arr){
  // flatten array and remove empty strings
  const cleanArray = arr.flat().filter(Boolean)
  // convert all strings as independent numbers (["1 1 1"] -> [1,1,1])
  const numberArrays = cleanArray.map(suite=> {
    return suite.split("").map(Number).filter(Boolean)
  })
  // batchMemory saves arrays of numbers before saving them
  let batchMemory = []
  // loop over our array of numbers arrays
  return numberArrays.reduce((acc,cur, i)=> {
    const index = i+1
  // save the current array of number in a temporary memory 
    batchMemory.push(cur)
  // we want to save two arrays of numbers as a single entry in our final result 
  // so each time the the entry index is a multiple of two,
  // we push the two arrays of numbers saved into batchMemory
  // in the final result (here the accumulator - acc - of our reducer)
  // finally, we clean up batchMemory to repeat the operation with the next arrays of number
      if(index %2===0){
        acc.push(batchMemory)
        batchMemory = []
        return acc
      }
    return acc
  }, [])
}

console.log(foo(arr))
```

Comment: Well the question wasn't really about solving the task but about improving function composition skill. This snippet do the right thing but at leas for me is less readable at first look.

Comment: Your snippet is actually less readable because it is written with nested callbacks. I have modified my code snippets with comments that clearly explain how it works. I know you've already accepted an answer, but I think my answer deserves an upvote because it's pure javascript, and more performant than using a lib.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a slightly different approach by having a look to a solution in pure Javascritp and convert this to Ramda.

`parse`

```js
const
    { compose, filter, isEmpty, map, not, o, split } = R,
    array = [['1 1 1', '', '2 2 2'], ['', '3 3 3', '4 4 4']],
    resultPure = array.map(a => a
        .filter(Boolean)
        .map(s => s
            .split(' ')
            .map(Number)
        )
    ),
    fn = map(compose(
        map(compose(
            map(Number),
            split(' ')
        )),
        filter(o(not, isEmpty))
    ));
    
console.log(fn(array));
console.log(resultPure);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd also suggest considering recursion for this kind of job

```js
const parse = R.pipe(R.split(' '), R.map(Number));
const normalize = R.pipe(R.reject(R.isEmpty), R.map(parse), R.of);

const fn = ([head, ...tail]) => normalize(head).concat(
  tail.length ? fn(tail) : [],
);

// ==
const data = [['1 1 1', '', '2 2 2'], ['', '3 3 3', '4 4 4']]

console.log(
  fn(data),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```